# if statement issue in drawRect

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, if-statement

Yes, yes. Shame on me. I am trying to draw in UIView and my code is:

```
NSString *str;

if(kmObj.metal!=@"" && kmObj.metalName2!=@"" && kmObj.metalname3!=@"")
{
   str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ + %@ + %@",kmObj.metal,kmObj.metalName2,kmObj.metalname3]; 
}
if(kmObj.metal!=@"" && kmObj.metalName2!=@"" && kmObj.metalname3==@"")
{
   str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ + %@",kmObj.metal,kmObj.metalName2]; 
}
if(kmObj.metal!=@"" && kmObj.metalName2==@"" && kmObj.metalname3==@"")
{
   str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",kmObj.metal]; 
}
[str drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10.0,234.0)
                forWidth:200
                withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]
             minFontSize:20.0
          actualFontSize:NULL
           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation 
      baselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines];
```

So, this code suppose to check if the Object contains more than one metal name record. If so, than it has to format string to form: Au+Ag+Cu ... My problem is that in output draw I can't get rid of the + signs where I don't need them. Is there something wrong in my if statement?

Comment: Can you provide an actual example string where the + signs appear in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `if (string != @"")`, use `![string isEqualToString:@""]` or perhaps `([string length] > 0)`. You need to make sure you are performing a **value** comparison, not a **pointer** comparison.

Anyway, I would write code like this:

```
NSString *outputString = @"";

if ([firstString length] > 0) {
    outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingString:firstString];
}

if ([secondString length] > 0) {
    outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@" + %@", secondString];
}

if ([thirdString length] > 0) {
    outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@" + %@", thirdString];
}
```

With this technique, you check each string individually, and only include a plus sign when you know another valid string will follow it.

Comment: it makes the same result. string!=@"" always worked fine before.

Answer (score 1):

String comparisons should take the form: `[stringA isEqualToString:stringB]`

From the docs: `When you know both objects are strings, this method is a faster way to check equality than isEqual:`

Plus, `==` for strings is weird anyways - they are non-primitives and you're wanting a value comparison.

**Also, you should take into account the possibility of having `nil` and/or `[NSNull null]` values** (depending on where these values are sourced). Your current test of whether or not they are equal to empty strings doesn't take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that you don't want the "+" sign? Then don't put it in your NSString.

So instead of

```
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ + %@ + %@",kmObj.metal,kmObj.metalName2,kmObj.metalname3];
```

do

```
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",kmObj.metal,kmObj.metalName2,kmObj.metalname3];
```

also use `[kmObj.metal isEqualToString:@""]` for your string comparison

Comment: LOL... please tell me that wasn't his problem.

Comment: well, from his question "I can't get read the + signs where I don't need them", I just assumed that he wanted to get "rid" of the + signs. Otherwise, that sentence doesn't really make sense. LOL

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad. I have misspelled it completely. Definitely, I mean 'rid' instead of 'read'.